# Overlap issues with jQuery Masonry in Firefox 8

Tags: jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I am experiencing the overlap issues addressed on the Masonry help section of their website. However, I'm only seeing this in Firefox, and it seems to have occurred only since I updated to FF 8. I had it working in all browsers by using $(window).load instead of the imagesLoaded plugin (which doesn't work in IE). Infinite Scroll + Masonry worked perfectly in FF until today. Any other suggestions to solve the overlap issues, when neither the imagesLoaded plugin nor $(window).load are solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using setTimeout fixed the overlap issue for FF. However this broke it in Safari. So the way I got this to work was kind of hack-y - I used imagesLoaded for browsers other than FF and setTimeout for FF.

I'd love to hear if anyone else has a cleaner fix. Thanks!